# State-of-the-art: unsupervised learning for patterns in text

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, text-mining, unsupervised-learning, topic-models

My gut tells me tried-and-true approaches like [*k*-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) may no longer be state-of-the-art approaches for unsupervised learning **with text data**, what with models like doc2vec and word2vec emerging lately.

What do *you* think is the "best" unsupervised learning approach for theme-finding in text data?